# My scrapy pagination works but it just show me the first page data for all pages

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

Im new to python and i mix up many example codes for my scrapy but it just show me the first page data for all pages. what is the problem?
My code is:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class HotelAbbasiItem(Item):
    reviewer=Field()
    DateOfReview=Field()
    Nationality=Field()
    Contribution=Field()
    ReviewText=Field()
    Rating=Field()

class HotelabbasiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'HotelAbbasi'
    allowed_domains = ['tripadvisor.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g295423-d320767-Reviews-Abbasi_Hotel-Isfahan_Isfahan_Province.html']
    def parse(self,response):
        items=HotelAbbasiItem()
        all_div_parts=response.css('div.hotels-community-tab-common-Card__section--4r93H')
        for part in all_div_parts:
            reviewer=part.css('a.social-member-event-MemberEventOnObjectBlock__member--35-jC::text').extract()
            DateOfReview=part.css('span::text').extract()
            Nationality=part.css('span.small::text').extract()
            Contribution=part.css('span.social-member-MemberHeaderStats__bold--3z3qh::text').extract()
            ReviewText=part.css('q.location-review-review-list-parts-ExpandableReview__reviewText--gOmRC>span::text').extract()
            Rating=part.css('div.location-review-review-list-parts-RatingLine__bubbles--GcJvM>span::attr(class)').extract()

            items['reviewer']=reviewer
            items['DateOfReview']=DateOfReview
            items['Nationality']=Nationality
            items['Contribution']=Contribution
            items['ReviewText']=ReviewText
            items['Rating']=Rating

            yield items
        NextPage=response.css('div.is-centered>a.primary::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if NextPage:
            NextPage=response.urljoin(NextPage)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=NextPage,callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Hello @Hny, I just checked your code by using scrapy's shell and it worked. Note what you're browsing by following the next button are the reviews.

Comment: My code is work and go to all pages but it just show me the first page data and repeat it for whole pages. what can i do?

Comment: Sorry, I don´t understand what you are saying. Let me know an example, please

Comment: I mean, in the code result i can see url of every page that paginated but every time just the first page data show. the first page data repeatedly show as result for every single page. for example scrspy goes to second page and show me the url of second page but just with first page data not second page data and so on.